# Lispy way to read user input from the keyboard in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, keyboard-input

I am writing a function for my Clojure program that reads user input from the keyboard.  If the user enters invalid input, the user is warned and then prompted again.  When using a procedural style in a language like Python, I would do something like this:

```
while 1:
    value = input("What is your decision?")
    if validated(value):
        break
    else:
        print "That is not valid."
```

The best I can come up with in Clojure is this:

```
(loop [value (do
               (println "What is your decision?")
               (read-line))]
  (if (validated value)
    value
    (recur (do
             (println "That is not valid.")
             (println "What is your decision?")
             (read-line)))))
```

This works, but it is redundant and seems verbose.  Is there a more Lispy/Clojurey way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
(defn input []
   (println "What is your decision?")
   (if-let [v (valid? (read-line))]
      v
      (do
         (println "That is not valid")
         (recur)))
```

Answer (score 8):

Factor out the println/read-line combo into a get-line function:

```
(defn get-input [prompt]
  (println prompt)
  (read-line))

(defn get-validated-input []
  (loop [input (get-input "What is your decision?")]
    (if (valid? input)
      value
      (recur (get-input "That is not valid.\nWhat is your decision?")))))
```

This is basically what your Python version does; the difference is that get-input is built-in for Python.